# Emulator shows loading

Tags: android, xml, emulation

My code in MainActivityListFragment states that the method OnActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle) is never used' and it turns out grey. I also can't add @Override before it. When I run the app, it keeps on loading instead of showing the list. I would really appreciate your help as I am doing this for a project :)

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.enxin.crystallise.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityFrag"
    android:name="com.example.enxin.crystallise.MainActivityListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivityListFragment

```
package com.example.enxin.crystallise;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by En Xin on 11/6/2016.
 */
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {


public void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] values = new String[]{ "Android","iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS",
            "Ubuntu","Windows7", "Linux"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OnActivityCreated` should begin with a lowercase `o`. Change `OnActivityCreated` to `onActivityCreated` and then add the @Override:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
// the rest of your method
```